# The Beta Codereview.StackExchange Versus StackOverflow.com

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, code-review-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

I have searched for a similar question, but I have not yet found it on Meta. I have not found anything specific as to policies related to asking about beta sites either - in this case codereview.stackexchange.com.

I have a question related to the beta site codereview.stackexchange.com. So, according to the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq), codereview is essentially about refactoring code (for performance), best practices, etc. not error debugging.

So, does that mean that in essence I should post specific questions about specific errors that I have in my code in stackoverflow.com, and specific questions about my approach or coding methods in codereview.stackexchange.com?

For example, say at the beginning of my coding efforts with a random Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) project, I encounter a specific error I cannot resolve. I go to stackoverflow.com to find a solution, and to post a question if I do not find the answer. By contrast, however, if I am working with a C# Treeview solution, and I want to refactor /reconsider  my approach to my XAML layout, I would go to codereview.stackexchange.com?

I ask because in the past, I have seen refactoring style questions in SO, and it seems that the new beta site is intended as the future site for all such questions.

Comment: If so, there needs to be a better linkage to that [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in), as my search for questions related to codereview.stackexchange.com did not reveal that enlightening answer, which generally goes over all the programming sites in nice summary detail.

Comment: I'd love it if that post was a bit more visible, it's my answer after all ;)

Comment: Well, I have to agree :) Its very thorough - but its not particularly visible unless you already know how to find it. Although, now that this post is up, its in the Linked section, so perhaps that will be sufficient to inform people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you've got it exactly.

- Your code doesn't work and you can't figure out how to fix it: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- Your code works, but you'd like it reviewed: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

For more on what exactly is in scope for Code Review, see their [faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq); specifically:

> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases

Comment: Mat, that makes sense, thanks. I believe I understand the differences more clearly now. That said, I wish there was more meta on codereview as to the scope of "performance", "correctness in unanticipated cases" and especially "security issues" - given the IT Security stackexchange site for the last part.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but if you have more precise questions about Code Review's scope you should look at (and possibly ask on) their own [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/). I'm not sure IT Security takes "is this specific piece of code secure" questions (but I don't know that site very much).

Comment: Ah, ok - I had entirely forgotten that each stackexchange site had its own meta as well - I do not see a link in the overall stackoverflow meta FAQ, perhaps its mentioned at stackexchange. I will check over there and see how they delineate such issues. As for IT security, you're right - the code I saw there when I looked involved an identification of a [potentially malicious script](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/malicious-php-bash-script-what-is-it?rq=1).